# 動画画面がフルスクリーンになったら画面回転が検知されない件

Tags: swift, xcode

Swiftで横画面にすると動画がフルスクリーンになり、縦画面にするとフルスクリーンからmViewControllerと同じ位置・サイズ（埋め込み）で再生するようにしたいと思っています。

縦画面→横画面：◯ 動画がフルスクリーンへ
横画面→縦画面：× 画面は縦になるがフルスクリーンのまま

どうやらフルスクリーンになった際に

```
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
が効いていないような感じです。
```

解決方法ご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

```
// 画面回転時に呼び出される
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    // 現在のデバイスの向きを取得.
    let deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation!  = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) {
        //横向きの判定
        mMoviewPlayerView.fullscreen = true
    } else if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation){
        // 縦向き判定
        mMoviewPlayerView.view.frame = self.mViewController.bounds
        mMoviewPlayerView.fullscreen = false
    }
}
```

Comment: `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation()`はiOS8で`Deprecated`なメソッドなので環境によって今後は動かなくなると思いますが、当件については画面の向きの判定に`will～`（つまりまだ画面は回転していない）のメソッドで、現在の向きを取得してしまっているのが理由だと思います。`toInterfaceOrientation`で判定してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: toInterfaceOrientationで判定させるようにしました。しかし、同じ状況です。そもそも横画面から縦画面にする際に、    override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {} を呼んでいないようです。